# Trouble keeping text in container

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I hope i get an answer, this is my first time on here.  However, when using bootstrap 3, when I shrink a web browser to mobile, my text with squeezes to fit the smaller screen as expected because i am using fluid.  However, the length extends beyond the container its in.  Here is my code

```
<div class="container-fluid2">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <a name="whatis"></a><h2 class="what">What is Gatehouse?</h2>
    <p class="history">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
             </div>
          </div>
    <br>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p class="family">
        <strong>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</strong></p>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
.container-fluid2{
    background-color:#731B16 ;
     height: 600px;
     color: #F7F24E;
    }  
.family{
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: left;
    }
.history{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.family, .history{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.what{
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the css you're using?

Comment: *"However, the length extends beyond the container its in."* do you mean vertically or horizontally? everything looks fine to me. Do you have any other CSS?

Comment: @MichaelCoker   When I am referring to is the length of the text.  The width of the paragraph squeezes to fit the mobile view as the length extends below the container.  I have the css

Comment: then remove `height` from `.container-fluid2` or make your font size smaller or something

Comment: @MichaelCoker  forgive me for being a novice but I am creating a single page layout where i have multiple full width containers that follow by a full width photo as the page scroll, if that make sense. When I get rid of the height become too small to fit any text in it

Comment: With the html/css you provided, you don't need that height. If your layout relies upon that height for some reason, update your post with relevant stuff as to why you need that height. I hope you realize there is a problem - you defined a height, but in mobile, the content height is taller than the room you've made for it. You're going to need to change something... either change the height, change the content, change the layout, something... I Don't know what to tell you without just guessing if you don't give more context.

Comment: I see what you mean.  The only items that are not properly responding are the one where I specified the dimensions.  Thanks!